# What is the MySQL equivalent of Postgres' C collation?

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm working on reimplementing a Postgres schema in MySQL, and one of the things I can't seem to find a clear equivalent for is Postgres' `"C"` collation.

```
id TEXT COLLATE "C" NOT NULL
```

What would be the equivalent collation for MySQL?

Comment: I would love now what would possess you to downgrade? =)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'm writing a MySQL adapter for an open source project that only has a Postgres adapter at the moment. The idea is to give users the ability to use the project with a wider variety of storage backends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C` is PostgreSQL's way of saying do not reinterpret the data, order it according to binary byte comparisons. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html)

> On all platforms, the collations named default, C, and POSIX are available. Additional collations may be available depending on operating system support. The default collation selects the `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` values specified at database creation time. The C and POSIX collations both specify “traditional C” behavior, in which only the ASCII letters “A” through “Z” are treated as letters, and **sorting is done strictly by character code byte values.**

MySQL seems to call it [`binary` the *"Binary pseudo charset"*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html). Whether or not they're optimized to take advantage of that is another question.

See also

- [The `binary` Collation Compared to `_bin` Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html)

Comment: it looks like `utf8mb4_bin` is probably the one he wants.